# Mean.IO server.js Debian

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I've just set up a new webapp by means of Mean.io.

I followed the official guide: http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-installation-install-the-mean-cli
This is the result when I execute the command `gulp`:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The string 'production environment' has wrong quote marks (looks like backticks). Replace with normal quotes:

```
debug('Production Environment')
```